# Compilation error for annotations in Java using maven-compiler-plugin 2.5.1 with java 1.8 and netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm newborn in writing anotations in Java. I was trying to write my own following this tutorial: [Playing with Java annotation processing](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/playing-with-java-annotation-processing.html)

I wrote everything like it is there, but during compilation I'm getting an error:

```
Bad service configuration file javax.annotation.processing.Processor Provider <my class> not found.
```

I'm using netbeans and maven with plugin maven-compiler-plugin v. 2.5.1. and java sources v.1.8.

In my pom.xml file I have (like suggested in page) following code:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <!-- Disable annotation processing for ourselves. -->
    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My OS is Linux (leatest ubuntu) and maven is that one integrated in Netbeans.

I was trying to google it, but nothing helped me. All tutorials were for older release of plugin and Java. I tried older release of maven-compiler-plugin but with no effect. I cannot switch to older version of java because of new features introduced in Java 8.

Thanks a lot for any pointing me how to fix it.

**Edit:**

Here is full list of my sources:

**Config.java**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(value = {ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Config {
    String name();
    String type();
    String defaultValue();
}
```

**ConfigAnnotationProcessor.java**

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes(
        {"sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.ConfigAnnotations"}
)
public class ConfigAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment env) {
        Messager messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
        annotations.stream().forEach((te) -> {
            env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(te).stream().forEach((e) -> {
                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,
                        "Printing: " + e.toString());
            });
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }
}
```

**META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor**

```
sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.ConfigAnnotationProcessor
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao</groupId>
    <artifactId>MotionAnalyser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        .... some dependencies ...
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                            <!-- Disable annotation processing for ourselves.-->
                            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument> 
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

And this is **log of my compiler**:

```
cd /home/xjuraj/Dropbox/Work/MotionAnalyser; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle /usr/local/netbeans-8.0/java/maven/bin/mvn clean install
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building MotionAnalyser 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ MotionAnalyser ---
Deleting /home/xjuraj/Dropbox/Work/MotionAnalyser/target

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ MotionAnalyser ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 6 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ MotionAnalyser ---
Compiling 27 source files to /home/xjuraj/Dropbox/Work/MotionAnalyser/target/classes
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.ConfigAnnotationProcessor not found
1 error
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.661s
Finished at: Mon Aug 11 19:56:16 CEST 2014
Final Memory: 12M/180M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project MotionAnalyser: Compilation failure
error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.ConfigAnnotationProcessor not found
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**Edit 2 and so on...**:

[Screenshot of my environment is here](http://s30.postimg.org/xi1wm49jz/Screenshot_from_2014_08_13_18_08_26.png)

[Screenshot of my folder structure](http://s12.postimg.org/hjdj38rks/screenshot.jpg)

**Output of non-integrated maven**

```
xjuraj@xjuraj-pc:~/Dropbox/Work/MotionAnalyser$ mvn -e package
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao:MotionAnalyser:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 27 source files to /home/xjuraj/Dropbox/Work/MotionAnalyser/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.ConfigAnnotationProcessor not found
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.ConfigAnnotationProcessor not found

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.ConfigAnnotationProcessor not found

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.ConfigAnnotationProcessor not found

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:729)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 14 15:10:26 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/187M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cheers, 
juraj

Comment: can you show your processor code?

Comment: sure, I edited my post and I included all my sources...

Comment: `@SupportedAnnotationTypes` value should be `sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.Config`, not `sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao.motionanalyser.config.ConfigAnnotations`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i forgot to change it after refactoring... Thanks. But anyway, I'm still getting the same error :-/

Comment: Try to remove the `<profiles>` tag from pom.xml. Only dependencies and properties.

Comment: nothing has changed. Still the same error.

Comment: how are you compiling the project? can you show your project package tree?

Comment: I'm compiling it through Netbeans environment automatically. Screenshot of my environment is here: http://s30.postimg.org/xi1wm49jz/Screenshot_from_2014_08_13_18_08_26.png I already checked names of packages, I think they are correct.

Comment: I have not used Netbeans, but are you sure that you have a tipical maven project structure? Don't `sk.lieskove301.jian...` should be inside `src/main/java` ?

Comment: Actually, it has structure like this. Netbeans just shows it differently. Here is screenshot of my folder structure: http://s12.postimg.org/hjdj38rks/screenshot.jpg

Comment: Sorry. It seems ok. Have you tried to compile manually in console? `mvn package`

Comment: Don't be sorry, it's OK :) I've tried to compile it by maven from Ubuntu repositories, but the same error. I turned on debug info, but I don't think there is something important. Output is at the end of my edited post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks a lot bigdestroyer for your time and help. I already found where the bug was. It was in pom.xml file. My structure was:

```
<project>
    [...]
    <dependencies>.... some dependencies ...</dependencies>
    <properties>.... some properties ...</properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        ... plugins & settings ...
```

But there were problem with tags *<profiles>* and *<profile>*. I removed them and it works like a charm now.

So my working pom.xml now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sk.lieskove301.jianghongtiao</groupId>
    <artifactId>MotionAnalyser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        ...dependencies...
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <!-- Disable annotation processing for ourselves.-->
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in this instruction:

```
<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
```

OP's answer has that line in Maven configuration, but he doesn't mention its importance.

I, too, tried to write an annotation processor and compile it with Maven. Addinng the line did the trick.

Comment: `project>build>plugins>plugin(maven-compiler-plugin)>configuration>compilerArgument`